# Python won't show me np.exp marketshare values

Tags: python, numpy, exp

I'm trying to estimate marketshares with the following formula:

```
c = np.exp(-Mu*a)/(np.exp(-Mu*a)+np.exp(-Mu*b))
```

in which a and b are 9x9 matrices with cell values that can be larger than 1000. Because the numbers are so small, Python returns NaN values. In order to enhance precision of the estimation i have already tried `np.float128` but all this does is raise the error that numpy doesn't have an attribute called float128. I have also tried `longdouble`, again without success. Are there other ways to make Python show the actual values of the cells instead of NaN?

Comment: What is `Mu` in the expression?

Comment: `Mu` is a parameter that is being estimated in the larger function.

Comment: Would using `c = 1/(1+np.exp(Mu*(a-b)))` work (based on the values you have)?

Comment: I'm running the code right now with your suggested code, and it looks like its working! Is this like an alternative notation for the same formula?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
c = np.exp(-Mu*a)/(np.exp(-Mu*a)+np.exp(-Mu*b))
```

Multipying the numerator and denominator by `e^(Mu*a)`, you get:

```
c = 1/(1+np.exp(Mu*(a-b)))
```

This is just a reformulation of the same formula.

Now, if the `exp` term is still too small, and you do not need a more precise result, then your `c` is approximately very close to 1. And if you still need to control precision, you can take `log` on both sides and use the Taylor expansion of `log(1+x)`.